# Looking for a function family that pinches the two sides of a square but linearly spread point at $~x=0~$

Tags: functions

I'd like to find a function $~f_i(x)~$ where $~i, \ x \ \text{and} \ f_i(x) \in [-1, 1]~$, that does that:

- the $~f_i(0)~$ are linearly spread over the $~y$-axis, i.e., $~f_{i+1}(0)-f_i(0) = 1$;
- the $~f_i(0)~$ has an horizontal tangent $~(\frac{\partial{f_i(0)}}{\partial{x}}=0)~$;
- for all $~i~$, stretches a little bit the plane vertically at $~y=\pm1~$, but keep an horizontal tangent at $~y=±1,~~ \left(~\frac{\partial{f_i(±1)}}{\partial{x}}=0~\right)~$;
- $f_i(x) = ±1~$ for $~i=±1~$;
- $f_i(x) = 0~$ for $~i=0~$.

I‘ve drawn a template below.

[image: The function I look forward]

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\partial{f_i(0)}}{\partial{x}}=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes, I want the tangent at along the vertical center of the squeeze to be flat (horizontal). I fixed my typo in the question.